# Installed npm-check -g, getting bash: npm-check: command not found when running it

Tags: javascript, npm, environment-variables

OS: Windows 10, Terminal: Git-Bash

- I installed `npm-check` https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check, both with the -g flag as well as a devDependency.
- When I try to run npm-check in the terminal, I get:
  `bash: npm-check: command not found`
- I checked that the package installed correctly in the list of globally installed packages:

```
$ npm list -g --depth 0
C:\Users\Iordache Silviu\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @vue/cli@3.8.4
+-- jshint@2.10.2
+-- mongodb@3.2.7
+-- nodemon@1.19.1
+-- npm@6.11.2
+-- npm-check@5.9.0
`-- pug-cli@1.0.0-alpha6
```

As you can see on the second to last line, the package is present in the list

My windows username is Iordache Silviu, and my user folder contains a space in it. This could be part of the problem but I am not sure?

I ran npm config get prefix to get the path of my npm folder, got this:

`C:\Users\Iordache Silviu\AppData\Roaming\npm`

I added the path of the node-modules in my environment variables paths:

- User variables Path:
- System variables Path:

In both of them I added these 2 paths

```
C:\Users\Iordache Silviu\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Users\Iordache Silviu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

I expect when I run `npm-check` for the system to recognize this problem and work as intended and explained on their website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check

Answer (score 2):

Try to installl using `--save` flag like ,

```
npm i npm-check --save
```

**UPDATED**

```
1)npm install -g npm-check 
2)npm install
3)npm-check -u
```

I have tried the same code in my windows . It runs perfect .
 Lemme know if your problem continues .
**Try it out .**

Comment: I just tried it and I still get the same message:bash: npm-check: command not found

Comment: When I type sudo npm install -g npm-check, I get: bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: I am running on Windows10

Comment: Will get back to you with new solution . @SilviuIordache

Comment: I tried:  **npm-check -u** , but I still get: bash: npm-check: command not found

Comment: Followed the steps in mentioned in answer ? @SilviuIordache

Comment: Yes, I eventually found the solution. Check my answer above, it had to do with where I put my env variables in (myUser vs <root> user)

Answer (score 0):

- When I opened a terminal as administrator from the root folder of the
  project(via File Explorer) , the command worked as intended.
- The problem I had was that the terminal in VSCode didn't have the same path as the one opened in File Explorer.
- Since I am using a work computer, I have 2 different users on this machine:  and , each with it's own set of Environment Variables.
- If you are in the same situation as me, be extra careful which Environment Variables you are bringing up when typing 'env' in the search bar of Windows. I though I was typing node-modules paths into my user, when actually I was typing them into the pats of the (admin) user on the work PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing a package with `npm install npm-check` it will not work. You need to install it with `npm install -g npm-check`. After that, it will work.

-g flag is used for download and install packages globally

Comment: Keep in mind I am not aware wath "i" or "g" does... so explain in your answer the difference to elevate the quality of the answer. Otherwise bots or users may mark it as "low quality answer" and your efforts has been for nothing.